# why $c_k=0 $ for all $k <-n<0 ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Some confusion in the  statement of Poles

**Statement** : Suppose that  $f$  has  a  singular point at $z_0$. Expand $f(z)$ as  a  laurent series on a  pointed neighborhood  of $z_0$ , say

$f(z)  =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k (z-z_0)^k$

A pole of order $n$  if $ c_{-n} \neq 0$ and $c_k=0 $ for all $k <-n<0$

**My confusion**: If  $c_k=0 $ for all $k <-n<0$ then $z_0 $will  become removable singularity

why $c_k=0 $ for all $k <-n<0 ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singularity is removable if $c_k = 0$ for $k < 0.$ The function $f(z) = \frac1z$ does *not* have a removable singularity at $z=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Pole  of order $n$  is given by  $$\frac{c_{-n}}{(z-z_0)^n}  + \frac{c_{-(n-1)}}{ (z-z_0)^{n-1}} +....+c_0 + c_1(z-z_0)+...$$

Now used the definition  of pole

A pole of order $n$  if $ c_{-n} \neq 0$ and $c_k=0 $ for all $k <-n<0$

$$\implies f(z)=\frac{c_{-n}}{(z-z_0)^n}$$

since $z_0$ is singular point  so
$ c_1(z-z_0)+ c_2(z-z_0)^2 +....=0$